# The code that i'm using to create a ListView is somehow making my setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); not work and i don't know what to do

Tags: java, android-studio, setcontentview

The code that i'm using to create a ListView is somehow making my setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); not work and i don't know what to do.

This is my very first app so i might be missing something simple but my activity_main is a screen with only one button that leads to another screen.

It was working just fine before but whenever i put the ListView code there the activity just goes blank. https://i.stack.imgur.com/bU7mS.jpg

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // This is what makes the screen go blank

        ListView lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);


        pedidos pedido1 = new pedidos("produto1","4.99");
        pedidos pedido2 = new pedidos("produto2","5.99");
        pedidos pedido3 = new pedidos("produto3","5.99");


        ArrayList<pedidos> lista_pedidos = new ArrayList<>();
        lista_pedidos.add(pedido1);
        lista_pedidos.add(pedido2);
        lista_pedidos.add(pedido3);

        pedidosListAdapter adapter = new pedidosListAdapter(this, R.layout.adapter_view_layout, lista_pedidos);
        lista.setAdapter(adapter);

        // It ends here

    }
```

It doesn't show any error messages when running the app, i expected it to work normally.

Comment: Is the `R.id.lista` height set to `matchParent`? If so, try setting a static height to debug. Sounds like lista is the top view and is currently blank

Comment: `R.id.lista` has a static height and it should appear only in the second screen after i click that giant button **Fazer Pedido**.

Comment: If lista appears on the second screen, does that mean the activity_main doesn't include the lista view? Check if the findViewById method is returning null

Comment: Create Log.i("TAG","VALUE") after assigned values and see if they contain data or null.

Comment: Sorry i'm still trying to check if findViewById method is returning null as Ertyguy asked, i'm having a hard time using the Log. I'll do `Log.i("TAG","VALUE")` when i get the log to work. EDIT: the other question "does that mean the activity_main doesn't include the lista view?" yes, activity_main.xml does not have the list view.

Comment: Ok so i'm 90% sure that findViewById is returning null and `Log.i("TAG","VALUE")` returns data and not null.

Comment: I think i see the problem. I've moved everything related to the list view inside the method that calls the second screen (the only screen the list appears) and it seems to be working. I feel kinda dumb now that i think about it.